# Server error reported when using NuGet to install package from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, nuget

I have an error when I install nuget from powershell:
[image: The server returned error 404]

But the same myget.org URL with works from web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message being displayed looks like it is from NuGet v2 which does not support package sources that end with index.json since they are NuGet v3 specific.

The 404 is because the NuGet v2 client is trying to use an endpoint which does not exist. The error message does not show the url which is failing but just shows you the package source being used.

So you can either [download NuGet v3](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) and use that. Or you can change your package source urls so they are NuGet v2 compatible: https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/

Another thing to check is that is the dbup NuGet package available from the package sources you have enabled. The dbup NuGet package is available from nuget.org but possibly not from the MyGet package sources you have enabled.